# Break and then continue in for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, break, continue

I've built a function that iterates through until it finds a value bigger than the value given to the function and then breaks.

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator OrderBook::find_price(PriceType price)
{
   std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator i = v_BuyOrders.begin();
    for (; i != v_BuyOrders.end(); ++i)
        if(i->get_price() >= price)        
            break;
   return i;        
}
```

I would then like it to test against another function, and if that does not hold then continue where the for loop was broken.  Is that possible?

Comment: Well, it could be *another* loop without the initializer part, because you would be using the iterator you've saved.

Comment: Why not `if (i->get_price() >= price && some_other_condition(i)) break;`?

Comment: Could you make a suggestion?

Comment: Could try-catch logic solve this for you? ie throw error and drop to catch block then continue?

Comment: @krowe Don't you think using try/catch logic when simple conditional checks would do, and when it's not about "exceptions" nor "errors" is a bit messy?

Comment: @JBL When I read this and there was no code posted it sounded like he was describing an error condition. Now it is clearly not what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that your 'another function' return true in case of success, how about something like:

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator OrderBook::find_price(PriceType price)
{
    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator i = v_BuyOrders.begin();
    for (; i != v_BuyOrders.end(); ++i)
    {
        if(i->get_price() >= price && another_function(i))
            return i;
    }
    return v_BuyOrders.end();
}
```

Since i is out of the for-loop, you can do it like that too:

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator OrderBook::find_price(PriceType price)
{
    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator i = v_BuyOrders.begin();
    for (; i != v_BuyOrders.end(); ++i)
    {
        if(i->get_price() >= price && another_function(i))
            break;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the second check inside the if and break only if it succeeds as well. Oh and don't forget brackets, they make the code readable! :)

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator OrderBook::find_price(PriceType price)
{
    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator i = v_BuyOrders.begin();
    for (; i != v_BuyOrders.end(); ++i){
        if(i->get_price() >= price && second_check(i->get_price())){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return i;       
}
```

This way, it'll perform your search, do both checks on your element, and break accordingly. If the second check doesn't succeed, it won't break continue from where it was in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The most literal way of translating your envisaging of the logic into code is this:

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator OrderBook::find_price(PriceType price)
{
    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator i = v_BuyOrders.begin();
    do
    {
        for (; i != v_BuyOrders.end(); ++i)
            if(i->get_price() >= price)        
                break;
        return i; // i.e. end()
    } while (!another_function(*i));
    return i;
}
```

It simplifies to:

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator OrderBook::find_price(PriceType price)
{
    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator i;
    for (i = v_BuyOrders.begin(); i != v_BuyOrders.end(); ++i)
        if(i->get_price() >= price && another_function(*i))
            break;
    return i;
}
```

Or, if you want to use Standard algorithms for a more declarative approach:

```
#include <algorithm>
...

std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator OrderBook::find_price(PriceType price)
{
    return std::find_if(v_BuyOrders.begin(), v_BuyOrders.end(), 
                        [](const AggregatedQuoteType& x)
                        { return x.get_price() >= price && another_function(x); });
}
```

Comment: Your simplification won't compile because in `return i;`, `i` is already out of range.

Comment: Great...and this will only search through elements of v_BuyOrders won't it?

Comment: @RuthO'Brien yes - each version searches between the specified iterators - namely `v_BuyOrders.begin()` and `v_BuyOrders.end()`.  `std::find_if` also increments from `begin()` onwards returning the first match, or `.end()` if there are no matches.